# Задать три фоновых картинки и их стиль

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

У страницы есть 3 фоновых картинки: самая верхняя , средняя,  и нижняя. Первая картинка  должна всегда полностью отображаться на экране - растягиваться под размер окна. Вторая и третья обрезаться (слева и справа), если экран слишком маленький, т.е. не должна растягиваться. Как лучше это осуществить?

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант?

```css
body {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vh;
  margin: 0;
  background:
    url('https://i.imgur.com/1B8pnOa.jpg') center top / 100vw 100vh,
    url('https://i.imgur.com/qdJuvYi.png') left 100vh / 50vw 100vh,
    url('https://i.imgur.com/nwwe3Hf.png') right 100vh / 50vw 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо! @CbIPoK2513

Comment: @НадяЧелядинова, если мой ответ вам помог, поставьте галочку слева от ответа

Comment: Хорошее решение. Возьму на заметку.